# How to concatenate multiple arrays across multiple axis in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following `numpy` array dimension: `[64, 897]`. This data is generated after each experiment. I have 8 subjects in total and I did the experiments 6 times per subject.

Therefore, I would like to have at the end a 4 dimensional array of the following size: `[8, 6, 64, 897]`.

How can I achieve this in `numpy` in python.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Take a look at `np.stack` specifying `axis=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @rafaelc, here is the solution:

```
total_slices = []

for i in range(8):
    slices_ = []
    for j in range(6):
        slices = result_of_experiment()   # This will return an np.array of shape: [64, 8970
        slices_.append(slices)

    slices = np.stack(slices_, axis=0)
    print("slices.shape", slices.shape)
    total_slices.append(slices)

total_slices = np.stack(total_slices, axis=0)
print("total_slices.shape", total_slices.shape)
```